# Android: How bound Service can be noticed about killed client?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, kill

I have an Activity and Service bound to it.

If Service is killed by system, Activity is noticed about it because of [ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName)](http://goo.gl/4qgRM) will be called.

But when Activity's process is killed by the system, is there any callback to Service? How can Service know that client was killed? (When the whole process is killed, there's no `onDestroy()` method call, unfortunately)

The only way i see now is the following:

I have callback list in my `Service`:

```
RemoteCallbackList<IModConnClient> mCallbacks
```

When i begin broadcast by calling `mCallbacks.beginBroadcast();` it returns me a number of clients. So, i can remember previous number of clients and check if it decreased. But it seems not to be really good solution. I'd like to have some callback, but unfortunately i can't find one.

Can anyone give a suggestion?

Comment: Why is your activity and your service not in the same process?

Comment: @CommonsWare, that's because i need to create service that will communicate with another applications using `AIDL`. The starting point for me was this Dev Guide: http://goo.gl/pJBqX . i have `android:process=":remote"` in AndroidManifest.xml for this service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

As stated in [`RemoteCallbackList` documentation](http://goo.gl/eN0zn), "*If a registered callback's process goes away, this class will take care of automatically removing it from the list. If you want to do additional work in this situation, you can create a subclass that implements the onCallbackDied(E) method.*"

So, i created a subclass for `RemoteCallbackList` and interface `IRemoteCallbackDied`:

```
   private interface IRemoteCallbackDied<E extends IInterface> {
      public void remoteCallbackDied(E callback, Object cookie);
   }

   private final class RemoteCallbackListWithDiedCB<E extends IInterface> extends RemoteCallbackList<E> {
      IRemoteCallbackDied<E> mRemoteCallbackDied;

      public RemoteCallbackListWithDiedCB(IRemoteCallbackDied<E> mRemoteCallbackDied)
      {
         this.mRemoteCallbackDied = mRemoteCallbackDied;
      }

      @Override public void onCallbackDied(E callback, Object cookie){
         super.onCallbackDied(callback, cookie);
         this.mRemoteCallbackDied.remoteCallbackDied(callback, cookie);
      }
   }
```

then, i created implementation for `IRemoteCallabackDied`:

```
   private final IRemoteCallbackDied<IModConnClient> mRemoteCallbackDied = new IRemoteCallbackDied<IModConnClient>() {
      public void remoteCallbackDied(IModConnClient mModConnClient, Object cookie)
      {
         Log.v("my_tag", "remote callback died!");
         /*
          * Some code
          */
      }
   };
```

and, finally, my callback list is defined just like that:

```
private RemoteCallbackListWithDiedCB<IModConnClient> mClients = new RemoteCallbackListWithDiedCB<IModConnClient>(mRemoteCallbackDied);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution too. It is [***onTaskRemoved***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) method of Service. It will let you know when an activity got killed. On the doc. it says..........

public void onTaskRemoved (Intent rootIntent)

Added in API level 14
This is called if the service is currently running and the user has removed a task that comes from the service's application. If you have set ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply be stopped.

Parameters
rootIntent  The original root Intent that was used to launch the task that is being removed.

If you want to know when the whole process is killed without onDestroy, you need to know about [***DeathRecipient***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.DeathRecipient.html). There is a [kind blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/binders-death-recipients.html).

I hope this answer would help you in anther way :)

Comment: Thanks but `onTaskRemoved` method was added in API level 14 only, but currently we targed devices with API level 7. Thanks for the information though.